# Simple http request and response

Tags: javascript

```
var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = "http://someurl.com?param1=one"
_body.appendChild(newScript);
```

My Question is

Is there a way to store the respose for this simple http request ?
(Like we have httpRequest.onreadystatechange if we are using ajax)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess youre trying check if a script file exists before adding to your code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly access the source code of an externally loaded JavaScript from within JavaScript.

You could (cross-origin rules permissions) request the script with XMLHttpRequest, or the script loaded might include code that exposes the relevant data in a global variable (or passes the data to a callback function you provide).

Comment: Oh. Like he wants to use a function inside a script file. Now it figures.